# Print to stdout without line break using IO.puts in elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to print a value to console without line breaks. For example If I try following

```
IO.puts("Hello ")
IO.puts("World")
```

I expect it to print in one line

```
Hello World
```

Edit: what I need to do is print without trailing CR

Comment: Please, next time try to state the question clearly. It’s absolutely unclear now what are you trying to accomplish: concatenate strings before printing? Print without trailing CR? Somewhat else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `write/2`, it behaves just like `puts/2` but doesn't append a newline:

```
IO.write("Hello ")
IO.write("World")
```

Also see the docs for [write/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#write/2)

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to use `string interpolation` to better effect:

```
greeting = "Hello"
subject = "World"

IO.puts "#{greeting}, #{subject}!"
```

output:

```
Hello, World!
```